# $A$ and $B$ nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, if $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$ then $\forall a \in A, \exists b \in B$ such that $a<b$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ and $B$ nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$ and $\sup(A) \not \in A$
>
> Prove: $\forall a \in A, \exists b \in B$ such that $a<b$

I started out with the fact that:
$$ a< \sup (A) = \sup (B)$$
And of course we know that 
$$b \leq \sup(B)= \sup(A)$$
So now we know that $\exists b$ that sort of "must be in the middle"
$$ a <b \leq \sup(B) $$
I don't know how to make this concrete, also is this element simply the supremum?

Comment: What is your definition of the supremum, and what properties have you proven for it? For example, if your definition of $\mathrm{sup}(X)$ is that it is a number $s$ such that (i) $s$ is an upper bound for $X$; and (ii) if $t$ is any upper bound for $x$, then $s\leq t$; then from $a\lt\mathrm{sup}(B)$ you can conclude that $a$ is **not** an upper bound for $B$, and therefore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following argument utilizes the second characterization of the supremum found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterizing_Property_of_Supremum_of_Subset_of_Real_Numbers):

Suppose $a \in A$. Since $\sup(A) \notin A$, we know that $\sup(A)-a>0$. So we select $\varepsilon=\sup(A)-a$. Now we have that there exists $b \in B$ such that 
\begin{aligned} b&>\sup(B)-\varepsilon \\& = \sup(B)-\left(\sup(A)-a\right) \\& = \sup(B)-\sup(B)+a \\& =a.
\end{aligned}

Comment: This is a good tool, yes we had to prove this as an earlier exercise in the book. It's a little bit less used than " the minimum of all upper bounds" property, but very useful indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By contradiction. Assume $\exists a \in A$ such that $\forall b \in B$, $b\leq a$. Then $\sup(B) \leq a < \sup(A)$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $ a\le \sup A=\sup B$, and because $\sup A \not\in A$, $a< \sup A=\sup B$. In particular, because $\sup B$ is the least upper bound of $B$, and $a$ is strictly less than it, there exists $b\in B$ with  $b>a$. If this were not  the case, then $a$ would be a smaller lower bound for $B$, which  is contradictory.

Comment: oh. I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a<\sup(A)=\sup(B)$, so $a$ is not an upper bound of $B$, because $\sup(B)$ is the *least* upper bound of $B$. Therefore $a<b$, for some $b\in B$.